# Unable to send parameters to server action method using angularjs $http request

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I am doing Ajax requests to server in following way:

**App Setup:**

```
var appRoot = angular.module('demoApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']);
appRoot.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
         $routeProvider
         .when('/', { templateUrl: '/ngPartials/_Login.html', controller: 'LoginCtrl' })
         .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/ngPartials/_Login.html', controller: 'LoginCtrl' });
        }
]);
```

**Factory:**

```
appRoot.factory('LoginResource', function ($http) {
    var loginResource = {
        response:{},
        get: function (param) {
            $http.get('/Login/Login', param).
             success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

                 this.response = data;
             }).
             error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                 alert('error');

            });
        }
    }
    return loginResource;
});
```

**Controller:**

```
appRoot.controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, LoginResource) {
    //Make a get request on login resource
    $scope.User = LoginResource.get(
    {
       Role: val,
       Email_Id: $scope.Email,
       Pwd: $scope.Password
    }, function (response) { 
    //do someting in callback function
    });
});
```

But I don't know what wrong I am doing in above code, the parameters (Role,Email_Id,Pwd) are not being binded to my server Action method when I do get request to it. The method is hit properly but the model values are not being binded.

**server side model:**

```
public class LoginModel
{
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public string Email_Id { get; set; }
    public string Pwd { get; set; }
    public bool IsEmailValidation { get; set; }

}
```

**Action method:**

```
    [HttpGet, ActionName("Login")]
    public JsonResult Login(LoginModel oLogin)
    {
       ...
    }
```

When I call above action method from angular, the method is being hit, but all the properties in the object oLogin are null. What going wrong with my above code?

**EDIT:**

Previously instead of $http, I was using $resource as follows and everything was working exactly fine.

```
appRoot.factory('LoginResource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/Login/Login');
});
```

Comment: Am I right in saying that you cannot pass a complex object with GET. Try using POST method and instead of params pass in a JSON object - data : param

Comment: I can't use POST instead of GET, 'cause I am using POST for other purpose. Also I tried sending JSON :  
var postdata = { data: param };
 $http.get('/Login/Login', postdata)  
But it also not working.

Comment: @SaurabhLprocks  have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28515650/189756)

Comment: @MohammadSepahvand - If I can't send complex object, then why previously I was able to send it using $resource?

Comment: Try adding the [FromUril] attribute to the LoginModel parameter. If that doesn't work, can you post your route config? http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: @BradBarber -  I am using mvc controller not web api controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In LoginResource, the second parameter to $http.get is the config, not the params...so change it to the following:

```
get: function (param) {
    $http.get('/Login/Login', { params: param }).
```